# FullCalendar timezones not modifying times on client's end

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I am experiencing a frustrating issue which I've been working on all night. Long story short, if someone in New York creates an event at 2Pm, I'd like that event to show as 8Pm for someone viewing the calendar in Europe (they are six hours ahead let's say).

My fullcalendar configs look like this:

```
  function renderSchedule(timezone) {
     var userSchedule = $('#user-schedule').fullCalendar({
             header: {
                 left: 'prev,next today',
                 center: 'title',
                 right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
             },
             timezone: timezone,
             ignoreTimezone: false,
             events: baseurl + "load_schedule",
             editable: true,
             defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
             firstHour: 8,
             allDayDefault: false
         }
```

I do have more options, but those should suffice for the purpose of this question.As mentioned in the docs, fullcalendar passes a URL via GET which looks like this:

```
         mysite.com / my_page / load_schedule ? start = 2014 - 02 - 02 & end = 2014 - 02 - 09 & timezone = Europe % 2FChisinau & _ = 1391660233815
```

Then, on the backend I am doing the following to convert from`MYSQL datetime` to`ISO8601`

```
$start = ($event['start']); 
$end = ($event['end']); 
$dateStart = new DateTime($start, new DateTimeZone($timezone)); 
$dateEnd = new DateTime($end, new DateTimeZone($timezone)); 
$dateStart - > setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone)); 
$dateEnd - > setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone)); 
$event['start'] = $dateStart - > format(DateTime::ISO8601); 
$event['end'] = $dateEnd - > format(DateTime::ISO8601); 
$newResult[] = $event;
```

The `$timezone` variable holds `Europe/Chisinau` which was of course passed by fullcalendar itself.

Here is what the above returns back to fullcalendar:

```
[{"id":"5","start":"2014-02-06T14:10:00+0200","end":"2014-02-06T15:00:00+0200","title":"My title"}]
```

Everything seems to be correct, but regardless of what I've tried the events show as 2PM.

**NOTE** This is important, I haven't mentioned this yet but I am passing in a timezone of my choice to the `renderSchedule` function. So, even though I am located on the East Coast of the US, I would like to be able to pass in a European Timezone and have the calendar render accordingly.

Also, I should point out that I'm using the beta version (2.0) which allows a timezone string to be passed (which I am doing) and uses moments via [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work from the demo. I updated your date format to include colons for the offset. Also the latest stable version of fullcalendar 1.6.4 doesn't have a timezone variable.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        header : {
            left:"prev,next",
            center:"title",
            right:"month,basicWeek,agendaWeek,basicDay,agendaDay"
            },
        ignoreTimezone: false,
        events: [
        {
            start: "2014-02-06T14:10:00+02:00",
            end:"2014-02-06T15:00:00+02:00",
            title:"My title",
            allDay: false
        }
});
```

If you are using the beta release 2.0, then you need to remove ignoreTimezone as this is no longer a parameter.

#### Updated Answer:

It turns out the issue was how the dates were being handled on the backend. Here is how I solved this problem.

```
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
            $timestampStart = strtotime($mysql_start_date);
            $timestampEnd = strtotime($mysql_end_date);
            $local_time_start = $timestampStart + date('Z');
            $local_time_end = $timestampEnd + date('Z');
            $local_date_start = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $local_time_start);
            $local_date_end = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $local_time_end);

            $event['start'] = $local_date_start;
            $event['end'] = $local_date_end;
```

Comment: I'm using the beta release which supports timezones and uses momement.js

Comment: In that case ignoreTimezone is set by default to false and your timezone parameter should be "timezoneParam" vs "timezone". Have you seen the demo in http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs2/timezone/timezone/?

Comment: I don't think you can change the value of ignoreTimezone as it doesn't exist in 2.0. Take a look at http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/wiki/Upgrading-to-2/.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the follow ups, I really appreciate it. I did see that demo, but in that demo they use the "timezone" parameter, are you still suggesting I change it to `timezoneParam` ?

Comment: I just double checked the docs and timezoneParam is only specified on the event. timezone parameter should work. Have you tried adding ":" to your offsets?

Comment: Yes, when I use DateTime::ISO8601 in PHP, the offsets have no colons, when I use DateTime::ATOM, the colons are placed in the offset. However, neither works. It's so odd. I am surprised there is no PHP example out there.

Comment: What I don't understand is, regardless of what I'm doing on my end it appears that the response I'm sending to fullcalendar is *correct*. The JSON response has start and end times which are formatted with the appropriate time offsets. Am I missing something here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46972/discussion-between-marcrazyness-and-what-have-you-tried)